# Can you get sued as a Smart Contract Developer?

Tags: solidity, security, legal

I recently started work as a Smart Contract Developer.

As a developer, can you get sued if the smart contract you deployed gets exploited and people lose alot of money?

I think many of us work in small teams where you dont sign a contract or something like that. You just start building. So far I never even thought of any legal responsibilites, but better be safe than sorry. Bugs happen all the time.

Glad if someone can answer me that question.

Comment: Hey there. I would advise to ask a blockchain-savvy lawyer and not seek legal advice here.

Comment: The question is interesting but it is outside of the scope of this site. Perhaps you should ask to a lawyer to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I must agree that this is a legal, not technical matter, and thus a lot depends on your country, etc. I know of the few projects that have been hacked (private key stolen).

I once even saw it happen live, hackers printing tokens and selling them on the GATE.io exchange. I would assume there were lawsuits there. As the developers were accused of faking the hacking and actually stealing the money themselves.

That said, if you or your team are working on a serious project, you should also have a serious lawyer.